# How to "query" a (game) server for data, by sending a message and recieving info like status, players online, etc

Tags: c#, networking

A small C# game I am making runs as a client and server. I would like to send a message to the server as quickly as possible and have the server return stats such as players online, status, server name, etc, to be able to create a list of online servers with some simple stats.

The most similar example I can think of is Minecraft:
[image: http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8772/5l16.png]

We use the [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) library to handle connections to servers, however, connecting to them takes far to long. Is there a quick way to send a request to a server and have it reply back with simple stats in order to make a server list like above?

Comment: My apologies if this is better suited for GameDev.SE, however it is more about networking than game development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lidgren connections are thick, meaning it establishes a link with its own protocols before returning the connections to you, it would be best as you have stated to use a different method.

One of the fastest solutions would be built directly on a UDP socket (see [UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.udpclient) to help you with this) on which you fire out requests to your list of endpoints, and just parse returns.  Note that UDP is *connectionless* and issues no guarantees about the returns (one may occasionally get dropped).  It does offer some checksum capability so you don't really have to worry about corrupted responses.  For a game server polling application such as this, I'd say that UDP will work fine, and is in fact an unspoken industry standard to do it this way.  Just fire up Wireshark and launch your favorite game, chances are it uses a simple UDP datagram solution.

Comment: It seems the UdpClient needs to run on a different port than the server correct? This means users will have to port forward 2 ports... right?

Comment: Only the servers responding would have to have this other port forwarded.  For the client, the router should trigger and add your source to NAT, etc., complicated stuff that should work automatically.  If a single-port server is absolutely critical to your design, you would have to rework your netcode to sit on top of said UDP socket, which can involve a lot of work for you, and potentially nullify the benefit of Lidgren.  A second port is acceptable in most cases.  Source engine games use an array of ports for this purpose, actually.  In short, yes.  I would recommend the 2-port solution.

Comment: Hmm, I got it working by moving the "query" code to TCP, and leaving the actual game server code from lidgren on UDP

Comment: Hmm, TCP will be slower than UDP generally.  It will ensure a response though.  I guess it depends on how many servers you're querying.  Good to know it's working!